# PHP The value captured from the radio button is "On"

Tags: php

I'm trying to capture question ids and their answers. The problem 
is that the value is "ON" when I print the array, it has the 
question number correctly in the first cell but then the value in the 
second cell is "ON". Here is my code:

```php
function get_questions($quiz_id)
{
    include'connection.php';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select id,question,option1,option2,option3,option4,answer from questions where quiz_id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$quiz_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($qid,$question,$option1,$option2,$option3,$option4,$answer);
    $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $question;
        echo "<br/>";
        ?>
        <form  method="POST"action="">

            <input type="radio" name="radio[<?php echo $qid; ?>]" ]value="x"><?php echo $option1;?><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="radio[<?php echo $qid; ?>]" ]value="y"><?php echo $option2;?><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="radio[<?php echo $qid; ?>]" ]value="z"><?php echo $option3;?><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="radio[<?php echo $qid; ?>]" ]value="f"><?php echo $option4;?><br/>

            <!--<input type="radio" name="radio[<?php echo $qid; ?>]" ]value="<?php echo $option2;?>"><?php echo $option2;?><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="radio[<?php echo $qid; ?>]" ]value="<?php echo $option3;?>"><?php echo $option3;?><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="radio[<?php echo $qid; ?>]" ]value="<?php echo $option4;?>"><?php echo $option4;?><br/>
            -->

        <?php
    }
    ?>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" > 
        </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $answers=$_POST['radio'];
        print_r($answers);
        // Iterate through each answer
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not generating valid html. You open a new `<form>` tag for each question in the `while` loop, but only close one of them outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a simple syntax error:

```
 ]value="x">
```

This square bracket is changing the name of the attribute from `value` to `]value`, so there is no value to be captured upon submission.

Also, make sure to move the opening `form` tag outside of your loop:

```php
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    ...
    <form  method="POST"action=""> // <- this here opens a new tag with each iteration
```

because you close the tag *outside* the loop, meaning you're not creating valid html.

And while we're here, I'd suggest the alternative syntax when you have mixed php and html code:

```php
<form method="POST" action="">
    <?php while ($stmt->fetch()): ?>
        <input type="radio"...
        ...
    <?php endwhile ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

It makes it more readable and easier to follow than having to match curly braces.

Comment: the ] was not the problem . i just moved the from outside the loop and closed it after the while loop everything went well . thanks a lot

Comment: @AhmedMaged Interesting, because when I test it in a correctly opened and closed form with `]value`, it produces the same problem (the value captured is "on").